# Remove Leading zeroes from an ArrayList of integers

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `integers`, I want to remove all the leading zeroes, code seems all right but U am getting unusual output.

**Input:**

> 0 0 0 1 9 9

**Output:**

> 0 1 9 9

**Expected output:**

> 1 9 9

```
public class Solution {
    public ArrayList<Integer> plusOne(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        int flag=0;
        //System.out.println(a.size()+"   "+a.get(2));
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        {
            if(flag==0)
            {
                //System.out.println("val of  i="+i+"     "+a.get(i));
                if(a.get(i)==0){
                    a.remove(i);
                    //System.out.println(flag);
                }
                else
                {
                    //System.out.println("flag="+flag+"     i="+i+"   value"+a.get(i));
                    flag=1;
                    //System.out.println("flag="+flag+"     i="+i+"   value"+a.get(i));
                }   
            }
            if(flag==1)
                break;
        }
        System.out.println();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't remove elements from a list you are currently iterating through. Instead you should create an other list where you collect the elements to remove, or use an iterator for the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the leading zeros by just searching for the first non-zero value, and then clearing the preceding sublist:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
int i = 0;
while (it.hasNext() && it.next() == 0) {
  ++i;
}
list.subList(0, i).clear();
```

Removing a block of the list like this can be more efficient than removing the elements one at a time. e.g. if you removed them one at a time, `ArrayList` would shift all of the tail elements one position along each time, so the removal would be O(n^2).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `i` is incrementing while `a.size()` is shrinking. When `i==0` you remove element `0` so all the values shift down 1, and next you remove element 1 but element 0 is also 0 so you skip this. i.e. you are only removing half the leading zeros.

BTW You should be able to confirm this by stepping through your code in your debugger. Helping you understand your code and find bugs is what it is for.

The simplest change is

```
 for (int i = 0, max = a.size(); i < max; i++)
```

and

```
     // you only want to check the first element.
     if (a.get(0) == 0)
         a.remove(0);
```

A more efficient way of doing this is to find the first element which is not 0 and return a sub list

```
public static List<Integer> trimLeadingZeros(List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (list.get(i) != 0)
            return list.subList(i, list.size());
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're removing elements from the list while you're iterating over it. When `i = 0`:

```
a.remove(i);
```

removes the first element of the list and all elements are shifted: the 2nd becomes the 1st, etc. Then in the `for` loop, `i` is set to 1 after that. Hence, the second element is ignored: it became the first after the remove operation and `i` jumped over it because it was incremented.

The ugly solution would be to have `i--;` right after `a.remove(i);` to account for that shift.

However, a better solution would be to use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

```
public ArrayList<Integer> plusOne(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    ListIterator<Integer> it = a.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && it.next() == 0) {
        it.remove();
    }
    return a;
}
```

This code retrieves it with [`listIterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator--). While there are still elements and the next element is 0, we remove it with [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove--).

Answer (score 0):

Logic: anytime you see 0, loop from that point to the end, if inside that loop you see anything other than 0, break out from that loop.

Code:

```
    //a is arrayList;
     int count = 0;

   for(int c = b; c < size; c++){
                            if(a.get(c) == 0 )
                            {
                                count++;

                            }
                    }

 //size = 10,saw zero at 6th position that means leading zeros has to be 4,
 // b is when I first saw 0

        if(count == (size -b)) {}
         else {
        //else we just copy
        ret.add(b, a.get(b));
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the ArrayList and if you encounter 0 just remove it.

```
while (i < a.size() - 1 && a.get(i) == 0) {
            a.remove(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution:
`while(a.get(0)==0) { a.remove(0); }`